# Get instance function from header file

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone-privateapi

I am currently testing private frameworks for IOS and currently I'm trying to figure out how to check if Night Shift is enabled. For reference, the header file I am working with is located [here](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/995b3bb9011192afcd70eed8fb73f1b6688c52f2/PrivateFrameworks/ControlCenterUI.framework/CCUINightShiftSectionController.h).

And here is the code I am using below:

```
  if (!(NSClassFromString(@"CCUINightShiftSectionController"))) {
            dlopen("System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ControlCenterUI.framework/ControlCenterUI", RTLD_LOCAL);
}

     NSObject *manager = [NSClassFromString(@"CCUINightShiftSectionController") performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"_defaultFontTight")];

            NSLog(@" ok= %@", manager);

        }
```

From that file, I got the data for `_defaultFontTight` to print in the NSLog just fine, but what I'm struggling with is how do I get the instance functions? More specifically, everything below that start with a `-`  symbol. I can only get info from a `+`
 symbol.

If I were to switch out `_defaultFontTight` with `enabled` then I get the following:

```
2017-07-02 18:09:35.382109-0400 Testing[809:96270] +[CCUINightShiftSectionController enabled]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1b7d5e420
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**

I tried this code below:

```
id myInstance =[NSClassFromString(@"CCUINightShiftSectionController") new];
[myInstance performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"enabled")];
```

For some frameworks, it gets the instance variable values sucessfully, while for most it just returns `null` or errors such as `[core] "Error returned from daemon: Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=9 "(null)""`

Answer (score 1):

Try create an *instance* of your class first if you wish to call instance methods. E.g. something like:

```
id myInstance = [NSClassFromString(@"CCUINNightShiftSectionController") new];
... [myInstance someInstanceMethod] ...
```

HTH

Comment: Thank you for your response, but right after pasting the code I am getting errors `/Users/Mathew/Desktop/Testing/Testing/ViewController.m:38:22: Implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to '__strong id *' is disallowed with ARC` and  `Pointer to non-const type 'id' with no explicit ownership`

Comment: Apologies, typo in answer, fixed, it is `id myInstance...` no `*`

Comment: Ok, so now the first line works, but now I can't get the second line of code. In the header code there's `- (BOOL)enabled;` and `- (id)_aggdKey;` for example, and using  `[myInstance _updateState];` returns `No known instance method for selector 'enabled'`

Comment: Well that's a seperate issue, you'll get that error if the object you created isn't the type you expect (and so it doesn't have the instance method you expect). Check the types of all your variables (in the debugger) and you'll probably find it. If not ask a new question showing the code you now have, giving the types the debugger shows, etc. and somebody will undoubtedly help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that you are using private frameworks (not documented), and the header file that you are referencing to it, is corresponding to iOS 10.2, so make sure to make your tests on a real iPhone running the same iOS version.

For your calls, try to make them like this:

```
id myInstance = [NSClassFromString(@"CCUINightShiftSectionController") new];
if ([myInstance respondsToSelector:@selector(someInstanceMethod)]) {
    [myInstance performSelector:@selector(someInstanceMethod)];
}
```

Also i note that "CCUINightShiftSectionController" is looking to be a "UIViewController" subclass, and it will not be well initialized using the "new" initializer, so you may have null or wrong results.

Good luck to make it working.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure private headers match the iOS version of your device. Otherwise you might get errors when trying to instantiate non-existing classes or call methods they don't implement.
2. Link to frameworks you want to use. You can't just allocate a class. You need to link your application to the framework that contains the class. Otherwise `NSClassFromString` will return `nil`. They're various ways you can do that but for now `dlopen("/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ControlCenterUI.framework/ControlCenterUI", RTLD_LAZY)` would be the simplest.

With that out of the way you will be able to call anything you want from private frameworks. But it doesn't mean it will actually work. Most private APIs are protected by entitlements and wouldn't work without jailbreak. And there's always a problem with figuring how to actually use them. You can't just call a random method and expect it to work. You might need to do some initialization. The only way to figure that out is to disassemble the methods and applications that call these methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in this way. Declare protocol with methods that you want to use.

```
@protocol TestPrivateMethods <NSObject>
- (BOOL)enabled;
@end
```

Then do it in this way :

```
id myInstance = [NSClassFromString(@"CCUINNightShiftSectionController") new];
NSLog(@"enabled %d", [(id<TestPrivateMethods>)myInstance enabled]);
```